# Is there any way to detect Software Version OR Kernel Version of connected host devices without using SNMP

Tags: ios, swift, networking, operating-system, snmp

My question is exactly what the title said, Is there any way to detect Software Version OR Kernel Version of connected host devices without using SNMP? i have achived the software versions of host devices using SNMP in iOS(swift). but that requires enabling of snmp in host devices and i don't want to work that way, i want to fetch that info just like other LANScanners fetch the other info like ip, names and mac address of the host devices without any enabling in host devices, just like this example, this scanner (https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan) fetches the info like name, device type and mac address. can i change this library to get the software or kernel version? if yes than a little guidance will be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: [iOS 11 removed the ability for applications to view MAC addresses at all](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan/issues/23), so this library no longer has the ability to get any information about network devices beyond the IP address.

That being said:

> can i change this library to get the software or kernel version?

No, because that isn't possible.

The MMLanScan library you're looking at used the MAC address to determine the manufacturer of a device. This is possible because the first three octets of the MAC address identify the manufacturer. The MAC address doesn't contain any information about the software currently running on a device -- it's a fixed identifier, after all, and can't change to reflect changes in software!

There is no generally applicable way to get the versions of software running on a network device. SNMP is about the only standard method I can think of, and, as you've discovered, no agent is present by default on most consumer devices.

Comment: SNMP is the standard from IETF, while different vendors (Apple/Microsoft/Cisco for instance) can have their own standards (WMI/PowerShell for Microsoft).

Comment: I'm not sure that's an appropriate comparison. WMI is a software interface, not a network protocol, and PowerShell is a scripting language.

Comment: Unfortunately, both WMI and PowerShell are more than "software interface" and "scripting language", as they also include the supporting infrastructure to enable remote management.

Comment: @duskwuff my only issue with SNMP is that it needs enabling on the host devices in order to discover them, but the requirement with my work don't want to the user to enable SNMP first. so is there any way to enable snmp through my iOS xcode app and didn't require user to go enable this himself?

Comment: @LexLi But i want it to work on all devices(Apple/Microsoft). can we implement the features of Powershell in my iOS app? if yes than how? or is there any other way?

Comment: @shahtajkhalid "I want it all" is possible, but complex. Since SNMP is not enabled by default, you have to use the vendor specific ways on individual platforms (do things differently for different types). Too broad to comment more.

Comment: @shahtajkhalid I think you're confused. There is no SNMP agent present to "enable" on iOS. Nor is it feasible to implement one in an application -- the agent would only be available when the application was running.

Comment: @duskwuff I know this. i was taking about enabling SNMP on MacOS (it is present there) and on Windows.

Comment: @shahtajkhalid You literally asked, in your earlier comment, whether there was "any way to enable snmp through my iOS xcode app". To which the answer is, no, there is no SNMP agent present to enable on iOS.

Comment: @duskwuff I meant enabling the Snmp present in Mac/Windows through an iOS app. But thanks for your direction i got the clear understanding.